# POSIX regex functions required and missing

Tags: c, regex, msys, msys2

when i trying to compile an old c source code using msys2 this error happens:

"configure: error: POSIX regex functions required and missing!"

Please any idea? Is that a library that can be added or it's an error related to the code itself?

Comment: Have you tried to search in the code for this message to see if it is a error related to the code itself ?

Comment: It looks to me like 'configure' is looking for the POSIX regex functions and not finding them. This is happening way before any actual compilation IMHO.

Comment: @CharlieBurns yes, It seems close. have you any ideas about POSIX regex library?

Comment: You probably need libregex installed and the headers also ( regex.h ). Google libregex.

Comment: I assume to code uses autoconf. You should have a `configure` script somewhere. Try to find `POSIX regex` in it, and you should find hints about what it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want to build an MSYS2 or a native program. Anyway ..

MSYS2 has the following regex libraries. You can search for them yourself via:

```
pacman -Ss regular
```

From the mingw{32,64} (i.e. native) repositories:

```
mingw-w64-{x86_64,i686}-oniguruma
mingw-w64-{x86_64,i686}-pcre
```

From the msys2 (i.e. Cygwin-like msys-2.0.dll linked) repository:

```
libpcre
libpcre16
libpcre32
libpcrecpp
libpcreposix
pcre
```